# Three20 error with xcode 4.0.2

Tags: xcode4, three20

i get this error:

shell script Invocation Error
Env: python: No such file or directory

run custom shell script "lint"

PhaseScriptExecution Lint /Users/Nasser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-fgspuusakfyzczfehhbduewymfmp/Build/Intermediates/Three20Core.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Three20Core.build/
Script-668E63EA131A42F500ACE4AB.sh

cd /Users/Nasser/Documents/test2/abc/three20/src/Three20Core

/bin/sh -c /Users/Nasser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/abc-fgspuusakfyzczfehhbduewymfmp/Build/
Intermediates/Three20Core.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Three20Core.build/Script-668E63EA131A42F500ACE4AB.
sh

env: python: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

you need to install python.

The best way is to use MacPorts. Download and install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), then install Python via MacPorts by typing the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo port install python26 python_select
sudo python_select python26
```

Comment: I have a new iMAC and python is already installed. I get this error when building Three20 on Xcode 4.02

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out myself.

i changed in each Three20 project the line in: "build phases > lint > shell" to:
 **/usr/bin/env /opt/local/bin/python2.6 ../scripts/lint**